# How to customize numpy reshape process?

Tags: python, numpy

A simple question, say I have an array `I` of shape `(1,2,H,W)`, for which the second axis is a `2-class` probability distribution, I want to reshape it to array `I_re` of shape `(2,H*W)`, and preserve the probability distribution, i.e., the first axis sum to 1, then I do some computation on it to generate a array `I_re_processed` of shape `(2,H*W)`, then with the same way of tranforming `I` to `I_re`, I want reshape `I_re_processed` back to same shape of `I`, which is `(1,2,H,W)`, but I dont have idea of how to do it in numpy, since numpy reshape seems does not have this kind of support, can someone help?

EDIT: the array is generated from some intermediate layer of an another program, `(1,2,H,W)` is just H*W pairs of 2-class distribution(adds to one), I want to reshape it to (2,H*W), which is more understandable and easier to do further computation, with I.reshape(2,H*W) I can transform I, but problem is rows of the transformed (2,H*W) array does not add to 1, which means the pairs is misplaced

Comment: [reshape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) is all about: *Gives a new shape to an array without changing its data.* As you seem to want to the data, it's not within the scope of reshape. Your task is probably a not-so-complex pipeline of reshape/broadcasting and summing. But for help with that, i think you need to be more precise!

Comment: an array `I` of shape `(1,2,H,W)`, the second axis is a `2-class` probability distribution, means the pair add to 1, I want to reshape it to `(2,H*W)`, there is `H*W` pairs, this first axis add to 1, but numpy reshape does not preserve the pairs, is that clear?

Comment: No it's not (to me). First it's unclear why you have an additional first unused dimension. Second: it's not a pair of two scalars; it's a pair of two matrices (+ some unused dim), when dim 1 (len=2) is selected. And for further work: edit your question (instead of using comments).

Comment: @sascha, I EDIT it, please take a look, thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "rows"? In your initial array, I'd expect `.sum(axis=1) == 1`, and in the final one, I'd expect `.sum(axis=0) == 1`. Do I have the axes correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to provide a concrete example.  The description as it stands is unclear.  I think @Eric and I both got the same picture:

Construct a 3d array which sums to 1 along the first axis (your initial size 1 dimension is just noise):

```
In [182]: x = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)/12
In [183]: x
Out[183]: 
array([[ 0.        ,  0.08333333,  0.16666667,  0.25      ],
       [ 0.33333333,  0.41666667,  0.5       ,  0.58333333],
       [ 0.66666667,  0.75      ,  0.83333333,  0.91666667]])
In [184]: arr = np.array((x,1-x))
In [185]: arr
Out[185]: 
array([[[ 0.        ,  0.08333333,  0.16666667,  0.25      ],
        [ 0.33333333,  0.41666667,  0.5       ,  0.58333333],
        [ 0.66666667,  0.75      ,  0.83333333,  0.91666667]],

       [[ 1.        ,  0.91666667,  0.83333333,  0.75      ],
        [ 0.66666667,  0.58333333,  0.5       ,  0.41666667],
        [ 0.33333333,  0.25      ,  0.16666667,  0.08333333]]])
In [186]: arr.shape
Out[186]: (2, 3, 4)
```

Verify that this sums to 1:

```
In [187]: arr.sum(axis=0)
Out[187]: 
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

But the reshape still sums to 1:

```
In [188]: arr2 = arr.reshape(2,12)
In [189]: arr2
Out[189]: 
array([[ 0.        ,  0.08333333,  0.16666667,  0.25      ,  0.33333333,
         0.41666667,  0.5       ,  0.58333333,  0.66666667,  0.75      ,
         0.83333333,  0.91666667],
       [ 1.        ,  0.91666667,  0.83333333,  0.75      ,  0.66666667,
         0.58333333,  0.5       ,  0.41666667,  0.33333333,  0.25      ,
         0.16666667,  0.08333333]])
In [190]: arr.sum(axis=0)
Out[190]: 
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

That suggests that you have something else in mind, such as some sort of sum over the last 2 dimensions?  In which case, what's the point to making a (1,2,H,W) array?  Why not just (H,W)?

Comment: thank you, the reshape method actually works, I'm computing the softmax loss, but it is strange for me that even after minus the max value of each pairs to preserve numarical stability, and then sums each pair together, I still get bunch of terms that is very much close to 1, but not:
`array([ 0.99999994,  0.99999994,  0.99999994, ...,  0.99999994,
        0.99999994,  0.99999994], dtype=float32)`

Comment: the (1,2,H,W) was generated by some intermediate layer of the prj I'm currently on, which is not writen by me, the first dimension means batch number, here the batch size is 1